# Did Luke attempt to retake the Jedi Temple on Coruscant?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker

After the New Republic gains control of Coruscant through the Galactic Concordance, did Luke Skywalker attempt to reclaim (or even visit) the former and still very much intact Jedi Temple, now converted to be the deceased Emperor's palace?

If Luke is so insistent on saving a tree just because it belongs to the Jedi and the Empire stole it, then shouldn't reclaiming the Jedi Temple be even higher priority?

If he did, is he aware of the Sith shrine beneath it? Which is something even Yoda does not know. And if he didn't, why didn't he?

Comment: This smells of multiple questions.

Comment: Maybe its too tainted by the dark side after years of Palpatines residence to be of any real use?

Comment: The canon answer is probably that we don't know yet.

Answer (score 5):

### Disney Canon

While, we don't know if he ever tried reclaiming it, we do know that Luke attempted to visit there on at least one occasion.

While on a quest to seek out more Jedi knowledge, in the Disney comic *Star Wars: Showdown on the Smuggler's Moon* (which takes place between episodes 4 and 5), Luke attempts to go to the Jedi temple on Coruscant.
[image]
He doesn't end up traveling there during the comic, but his knowledge of the force tree shown in *Shattered Empire* may imply that he ended up at traveling to the temple at some point.

Comment: Alright, so we established that he knows of the Jedi Temple. Still doesn't answer whether he attempted to restore the Emperor's palace back into the Jedi Temple after Coruscant was liberated.

Comment: @thegreatjedi I've updated my answer a bit with a more direct picture and to clarify how it doesn't fully address your question.

Comment: @thegreatjedi - Is there a way that I can further improve my answer?

Answer (score 3):

**Canon:** No information yet, anything between Episode 6 and Episode 7 is still mystery, especially information about Luke.

**Legends:** **Yes!**

Luke did use the Jedi Temple after the New Republic retook Coruscant, but he built his own New Order Jedi Temple (Headquarter) on top of the the old one. Luke and Mara even married there.
But the New Order Temple was destroyed during the Yuuzhan Vong War, reshowing the old temple once more.

It was used as a grave for a son of one of Palpatine's concubines.
- [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Headquarters) (with appearances)

However I couldn't find any source, that there is any structure related to the Sith beneath the Jedi Temple, only the fact that Darth Krayt rebuilt the temple and made it look dark and evil.

Comment: In current canon he went out to look for the temple if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @Oak that was not THIS templte he is searching for (or found) ;)

Comment: @souichiro the sith temple beneath the jedi temple is the new canon explanation why the jedi fell (mentioned in a thought in the Tarkin novel)

Answer (score 3):

The new canon comic "Shattered Empire" indicates that Luke is aware of the temple on Coruscant and what went on there.

> Luke raids an Imperial facility that holds the last trees that grew at the heart of the Jedi Temple

https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Shattered_Empire,_Part_IV

Answer (score 2):

Currently we have no indication if he is aware of the Sith shrine or not. But as hundreds of Jedi (including his father) didn't feel it it is unlikely he himself will.

As for him retaking the Jedi temple on Coruscant. In Canon this is unknown as far as I'm aware. Although I would say there is some indication that he has visited the temple as he knew about force sensitive trees that were once there (splintered empire canon comics). That I would count as an indication that it is possible he was there.

But aside from that it is unknown currently.