# Did Luke ever visit the Jedi temple on Coruscant?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, luke-skywalker

I know from [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/116520/90310) that at one stage Luke *attempted* to visit the temple on Coruscant, **But did Luke ever visit the Jedi temple on Coruscant?**

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't a duplicate of the linked question....?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot because that question doesn't cover whether he ever visited it.

Comment: @OrangeDog So bounty it... the questions are the same when it comes down to it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I don't think they are. Clearly you can visit somewhere without attempting to reconvert it at a later date.

Comment: With a very minor edit, the duplicate now also addresses this question. If you want additional (or updated) info, the best way to get it is by using a bounty

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty safe to say he would have. As [Wookieepedia notes](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Imperial_Palace)

- [The canon novel] *Tarkin* states that the Jedi Temple was converted into the Imperial Palace.
- The Special Edition of *Return of the Jedi* shows the Imperial Palace intact.

So we know the Jedi Temple survived the Empire, thanks to it being converted into the Imperial Palace. After Palpatine's death, it was used by Imperials until after the Battle of Jakku, at which point the Imperials left Coruscant. Nobody would have stopped Luke from visiting the Temple at that point.

Considering he seeks out the first Jedi Temple after his failure with his own temple, as well as [this canon comic](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Vol._2:_Showdown_on_the_Smuggler%27s_Moon) where he tries (and fails) to reach Coruscant during the Rebellion, there's no reason to think he wouldn't have gone there to see what Jedi secrets still lay hidden within.